# Polymer how to use Core-TransitionEnd

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I would like to execute a function after a ripple animation on an item has executed. I am using the following code for this at the moment :

```
<post-card id="card1">
          <img width="70" height="70"
          src="../images/start.png">
          <h2>Proceed</h2>
          <paper-ripple fit class="recenteringTouch"></paper-ripple>
        </post-card>
```

This is a card with an image and text. When I click on this, the following is done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("card1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
</script>
```

When I run this however, I am not able to see the ripple animation fully and it gets interrupted by the 'alert-dialog'.
How do I modify this so that the alert is only shown once the ripple is completed ?
I came across a method called 'core-transitionend' but haven't been able to figure out how to use it though. Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("paper-ripple").on("core-transitionend", function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
```

When someone clicks `#card1` the event should fire triggering your alert.

**Edit1**

To do a different alert for different cards just do this:

```
$("#card1").on("core-transitionend", function(){
    alert("Hello World 1!");
});

$("#card2").on("core-transitionend", function(){
    alert("Hello World 2!");
});
```

This will work as the `core-transitionend` event bubbles up the DOM tree.

**Edit2**

Without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("card1").addEventListener("core-transitionend", function(){
    alert("hello world");
});
```

Comment: I have several such cards in my HTML file, all with paper-ripples. This way won't all of them create the same alert ? How do I make many different ones ?

Comment: Another small question, how do I make the ripple span the entire card ? Currently it only covers a small region around the point of click. Thanks. @winhowes

Comment: If you add some css that pierces the shadow DOM using the `::shadow` pseudo class you can change the `.wave`'s CSS properties to adjust the height and the width (and you'll probably need to adjust the positioning too).